# How to find a word in picture and put another word in desired position?

Tags: linux, pdf, open-source, ocr

I am an IT specialist but i am doing financial clerk job a lot! I have to put cost centers in invoices (of the IT department) - by hand!

Maybe is there in Linux a technology or solution to automate it?

- I have invoice in PDF format (text, not scan)
- I can export it to picture PNG
- Is there a tool that allows to automatically search in the picture a word (e.g. `ID1234`) and put next to it another text (e.g. `CC1234`)?

Thank you

Comment: You could try `pdftotext file.pdf - > file.txt` and then use vim to find and replace words, depending on how many replacements you need to make.

Comment: you mean , you have to modify the image with the CC1234 text ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is exporting the file to PNG really a good idea in your case, or would it be more desirable that the edited invoice still be in PDF format?

Comment: Finding a word in a raster image such as PNG is likely to be harder than finding a word in a vector image such as PDF. If you really need to go via PNG then something like this OpenCV [Template Matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Does the position of the word change? If it is fixed (whether it is one or multiple words) there might be other solutions without converting the pdf back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

This may help , just try:
If you directly use pdf instead of image file , you can update the pdf like below ( Provided your pdf only has text or you want only text to change )

`pdftotext file.pdf`    => this will create a file file.txt

modify the text file file.txt for your need.

Then , change that back to pdf using (if you are in GNU Systems :
This will actually change the text file to ps ( post scirpt )

```
enscript file.txt -p new_file.ps
ps2pdf new_file.ps
```

Comment: Many thanks!!!! It's even better than pictures - work with text with all the power of awk, which I may have :)))

Comment: @Юля Pleasure . Have a great day .

Comment: @Юля if this answer did it for you, please mark it as accepted.